# Cauchy's Integral Formula over a contour

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

[image]

I'm confused with how to compute the integral in part(a). I know you need to use Cauchy's integral formula, so in part(a) you would have $f(z)=z^3-2z+5$ and $a=1$ which is a point in the interior of $\gamma$, so would you use the formula $f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz$ with $a$ and $f(z)$ defined?

Comment: would the answer be $8\pi i$

Comment: Answer seems good to me

Comment: and $6\pi i$ for part (b)

Comment: I'm unsure about part (c), any tips?

Comment: It doesn't really seem like you can directly apply Cauchy's formula to part c). However, you could factor the bottom completely, use deformation of curves, and apply Cauchy's formula 3 times.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck with doing the partial fractions for $\frac{1}{((z-i)(z+1)(z+2)^2)}$, I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer some time tonight. I'm in complex analysis myself, so this is pretty good practice

Comment: I split the contour into 3 parts instead of doing partial fractions and i got $\frac{544\pi i}{25}$, is that correct?